# How clean the DISK CACHE using JavaScript / TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, service-worker, browser-cache

I got some troubles with my PWA. I got on file named 'config.json' in my build folder. This one can be edit by user to change the URL back servers or other option.
The problem is:

After a few uses, it is stored in the **disk cache**. I used the Service Worker's(SW) Network-only method so that it was consistently loaded with the Network. But there is nothing to do, the SW continues to load it from the disk cache.
I created a button that allows to delete the whole cache of the application, unregister the SW and reload the application. It didn't work.
I uninstalled the application, cleared the site data under Chrome.
But it does not affect the disk cache.

The only way is in the Network section in DevTools, to right click, and select 'Clear browser cache'. And there it works. After that, the file is loaded from the root folder and the changes can be taken into account.
But on mobile there is no access to this option.

So I would like to create a button that deletes this disk cache. I looked for information on it but couldn't find it.

[The file config.json from disk cache]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtQtM.png)

My SW.ts from create-reate-app-pwa

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    }
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    }
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', ()=>{
  self.skipWaiting()
})

///////////////////////// CUSTOM service worker /////////////////////////////////  
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (new URL(event.request.url).pathname.includes('config.json')) {
    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
  }
});
```

The delete cache storage button

```
async function reload() {
    try {
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        await navigator.serviceWorker
          .getRegistrations()
          .then(function (registrations) {
            for (let registration of registrations) {
              registration.unregister()
            }
          })
      }
    } catch { }
    try {
      caches.keys().then(function (names) {
        for (let name of names)
          caches.delete(name)
      })
      localStorage.removeItem('i18nextLng')
      localStorage.removeItem("sessionID")
      localStorage.removeItem("username")
    } catch { }
    try {
      window.location.reload()
    } catch { }
  }
```

Modify service worker method, clean the cache application by TypeScript. Create button to clear all data about the PWA to reload all the files from root folder.

It works on desktop with Firefox and Chrome if 'Disable cache' option is checked in devtools

So how can I manually clean all the cache disk with typescript in a PWA?